# MaskMoney c/ Jquery ou JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angular

Como criar uma mascara para valores em Reais R$ ?
Tentei usar http://plentz.github.io/jquery-maskmoney/ porem não obtive sucesso.

Estou necessitando uma mascara que me apresente algo deste tipo:
R$ 0,01
R$ 0,10
R$ 1,00
R$ 10,00
R$ 100,00
R$ 1.000,00
Algo deste tipo!!!

Answer (score 1):

Use o MaskMoney desta forma:

Carregue o jQuery e o MaskMoney na página:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-maskmoney/3.0.2/jquery.maskMoney.min.js"></script>
```

Adicione a classe `.mascara` aos `inputs` que você quer criar a máscara:

```
<input type="text" class="mascara" />
```

Inicie o plugin:

```
<script>
$(function(){
   $(".mascara").maskMoney({
      prefix: 'R$ ',
      allowNegative: true,
      thousands: '.',
      decimal: ','
   });
});
</script>
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
$(function(){
   $(".mascara").maskMoney({
      prefix: 'R$ ',
      allowNegative: true,
      thousands: '.',
      decimal: ','
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-maskmoney/3.0.2/jquery.maskMoney.min.js"></script>
<input name="valor1" type="text" class="mascara" >
<br />
<input name="valor2" type="text" class="mascara" >
```

Answer (score -2):

tente usar o código abaixo:

```
$("#demo3").maskMoney({prefix:'R$ ', allowNegative: true, thousands:'.', decimal:',', affixesStay: false});
```

Comment: '.maskMoney()' funciona apenas com  a biblioteca específica, como informou o Sam em outra resposta.